# ActionController::RoutingError - uninitialized constant Photos

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I cant undestand, why error with route?

My routes:

```
devise_for :users
  get 'documents/delete'

  resources :freelancers
  resources :projects
  resources :documents
  resources :photos

  namespace :photo do
    resources :avatars, only: :destroy
  end

  get 'tags/:skill', to: 'projects#index', as: :skill

  root 'projects#index'
```

**avatars_controller.rb**

```
class Photos::AvatarsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_photo


  def delete

  end

  def destroy
    binding.pry
    @photo.avatar = File.new('public/images/default/avatar.png')
     respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
  end

  protected

  def set_photo
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

When I click link `<%= link_to "Remove", photo_avatar_path(@photo.id), remote: true,  method: :delete %>` display error in console: **ActionController::RoutingError - uninitialized constant Photos**

Comment: please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It your `avatars_controller` intead of:

```
class Photos::AvatarsController < ApplicationController
```

It should be `Photo`:

```
class Photo::AvatarsController < ApplicationController
```

Because in your `namespace` it is `photo` not `photos`.

Your routes posted above:

```
namespace :photo do
  resources :avatars, only: :destroy
end
```